# Monitoring the Full Disclosure mailinglist

Tags: security, email, monitoring, filter, rss

I develop web applications, which use a number of third party applications/code/services.

As part of the job, we regularly check with the Full Disclosure mailing list http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/ for any of the products we use.

This is a slow process to do manually and subscribing to the list would cost even more time, as most reports do not concern us.

Since I can't be the only one trying to keep up with any possible problems in the code I use, others have surely encountered (and hopefully solved) this problem before.

What is the best way to monitor the Full Disclosure mailing list for specific products only?

Answer (score 0):

Two generic ways to do the same thing... I'm not aware of any specific open solutions to do this, but it'd be rather trivial to do.

You *could* write a daily or weekly cron/jenkins job to scrape the previous time period's email from the archive looking for your keyworkds/combinations. Sending a batch digest with what it finds, if anything.

But personally, I'd Setup a specific email account to subscribe to the various security lists you're interested in. Add a simple automated script to parse the new emails for various keywords or combinations of keywords, when it finds a match forward that email on to you/your team. Just be sure to keep the keywords list updated with new products you're using.

You could even do this with a gmail account and custom rules, which is what I currently do, but I have setup an internal inbox in the past with a simple python script to forward emails that were of interest.